# Asymptotic ratio with two variables

Tags: asymptotics, infinity, ratio

What's the thought process when you try to get the asymptotic ratio with two variables x and y?

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1} - y^{n+1}}{2x^{n} - 2y^{n}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are positive.  If $x>y$, then, for large $n$, $x^n$ will be much larger than $y^n$.  As a result, the numerator will be "about" $x^{n+1}$ and the denominator will be "about" $2x^n$, and so the ratio will be "about" $x/2$.  As $n$ tends to infinity, this is indeed the limit.

You can work this out by dividing by $x^n$ to write the ratio as
$$
\frac{x-y\left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^n }{2-2\left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^n }
$$
and then considering what happens to $(y/x)^n$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Consider the $y>x$ case similarly.